# TDirectory.Delete seems to be asynchronous

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have observed that calling DirectoryExists(x) immediately after calling TDirectory.Delete(x) returns true IF the folder to be deleted has few files in it AND the folder is open (in Total Commander).

In other words:

```
begin 
  TDirectory.Delete('x', true);  <-- 'Delete' exited but the folder is still not fully deleted
  if SysUtils.DirectoryExists('x')...  <-- This returns true
end;
```

Is this a normal behavior?

The "solution" is this:

```
begin 
  TDirectory.Delete('x', true); 
  Sleep(1000);          //wait for Delete to finish
  if SysUtils.DirectoryExists('x')...
end;
```

Question: How do I know when the Delete is ready (how do I eliminate sleep)?

Note: Total Commander does not block the deletion of the folder (I guess) since the folder is deleted anyway (after a while).

Comment: Why would you do a call to `DirectoryExists` right after `TDirectory.Delete` anyway?

Comment: @R.Beiboer Maybe to check whether the directory has been deleted, since `TDirectory.Delete` lacks a result value.

Comment: @R.Beiboer:  Defensive coding, to try and check that the directory is gone before doing something inconsistent with its existence, amongst other reasons.

Comment: I AM checking for folder existence! And DirectoryExists returns true, since the deletion is not complete.

Comment: @NAZCA:  Yes, I understood that, I was just baffled by the "Why would you ..." comment.

Comment: If your intention is to empty a folder, you could call `TDirectory.GetDirectories` and call `TDirectory.Delete` for each directory. And then do a call to `TDirectory.GetFiles` and delete them all. That saves you the creation of a directory that already existed. and now you do not need the call to `DirectoryExists` anymore. Yes, it is more code for you to type, but it does what you need.

Comment: @R.Beiboer - Thanks. YOU ARE RIGHT. But that is not what I have asked. What I am trying to determine here is if this is a normal behavior and how trusted can this procedure be. Plus, is not that simple. When using GetFiles you need to do all kind of checks (set permissions do the files can be deleted, etc) and you need also to handle multi platform scenario.

Comment: What are you going to do? Do you want a program that works, or do you want to argue against the way MS designed the system. Just do what @R.Beiboer says.

Comment: Perhaps the Remarks section on the msdn page about RemoveDirectory gives us a clue? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx) _The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed._ This indicates that the call may return before the directory has actually been deleted.

Comment: @R.Beiboer - Thanks. That sheds some light into the issue. It also confirms that Delete is asynchronous (something not mentioned in Embarcadero's manual). This means that ALL code that uses Delete should use a Delay to prevent this kind of problems?  PS: I will accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Nope. I don't want to argue about why Windows was designed like that (at the time when I started this question I was not aware it is an OS-related thing). By discussing this here we might learn what other similar issue may arise from using Delete(). IT IS an interesting fact to learn that Delete is asynchronous. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look the msdn page about RemoveDirectory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx

The Remarks section says:

> The RemoveDirectory function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.

So probably another process also has a handle to the directory (virus scanner?).

If you need to empty the directory, then empty it instead of deleting it and recreating it afterwards. In the end you always pay for a dirty hack ;)

Comment: Example of where deletion/recreate of folder could happen: Total Commander has a function that allows you to put IO operations in a queue. So, you could delete a folder, then recreate it (copy another older with same name in the place of the deleted folder). Probably there are also other scenarios in which you depend on a folder of being deleted.