# How to cope with asynchronous removal of folders in filesystem::remove_all()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In some cases it's useful to have a temporary folder which is left behind for further inspection at the end of a program. I tried to use `filesystem::remove_all()` at the beginning of a program to remove old data and then immediately creating the folder back. This is minimum program illustrating the thing.

```
#include <experimental\filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
int main() {
    fs::remove_all("temp.dir");
    fs::create_directory("temp.dir");
}
```

It may work well, but, for example if you are compiling on Windows with Visual Studio 2017, if you have the temporary folder opened in Explorer, the removal works, but the creation fails (throwing an exception).

Under Windows this is basically due to the fact that the removal calls the Posix function `rmdir()` and this appears to return before the directory is effectively removed. The later call to `CreateDirectory()` fails with an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, which on a further execution doesn't happen anymore.

I've solved this with a very ugly delay or a loop which checks existence of the folder. In any case a very bad hack.

Now the questions: is this a problem limited to Windows? Is it an implementation bug? Do you know of any better and portable solution?

Comment: Try to rename `temp.dir` to something else before removing it (just forge some random suffix and append it to name).

Comment: This is definitely a sensible solution! Anyway I'd still would like to know if this is only a Windows problem.

Comment: It seems that it is normal behavior under Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809389/tdirectory-delete-seems-to-be-asynchronous
However, I don't know if the problem is Windows-only